# How to write '{' in inline event handler in the mxml tag itself?

Tags: flex3, adobe

How to write '{' in inline event handler in the mxml tag itself?
Suppose I want to write this and dont want to make a function for this two line statement...

```
click="{if { (_absences!='')chkAbsences.selected = true; chkRegularHrs.selected = false;} else {chkAbsences.selected=false};}"
```

Thanks guys...

Comment: Why don't you want to put this into a function?  What if the condition gets even more complex?  IMHO, readability is important, and having a more complex condition in MXML reduces readability in the long run.

Comment: yes but sometimes its only 2 lines, and I just wanted to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to escape that character. the same happens with the `&`. 
When compiling MXML, first it has to be a valid XML file. So, there are certain characters for which you need to accommodate and write ugly stuff like `if ( X &amp;&amp; Y ) ...`

[How to escape](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)..

PS: Do what @bedwyr says and use a `script` block for lengthy functions. you'll thank him/her later.

Comment: yes, this is what I was asking, escapes for these things. thanks. PS:I was thinking to use that only for 2 line code, but if it looks that ugly, I will better use function. thanks.

Comment: it's also a matter of avoiding bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple:

```
<s:Button>
    <s:click>
        <![CDATA[
            function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("CLICK!");
            }
        ]]>
    </s:click>
</s:Button>
```